# Find a value that could appear multiple times but only use other value once

Tags: php, mysql

Title maybe a bit confusing because I didn't know how to explain myself...

The problem I have is that I have a comments table in which is stored the instance that the comment is about, the comment itself and the user that commented, I'm trying to collect all the instances that have been commented by a user. But if an instance has been commented twice only select the instance once.

Currently I have this code which is returning all the instances

```
$test = @mysql_query("select * from comments where user_id = '$idd'");
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($test))
{
    $id = $result['instance_id'];
    $gender = $result['gender'];
    $name = $result['name'];

    $test2 = @mysql_query("select * from media_link where instance_id = $id");
    $result2 = mysql_fetch_array($test2);

    $media = $result2['media_id'];

    $test3 = @mysql_query("select * from comments where instance_id = $id");
    $result3 = mysql_fetch_array($test3);
    $comments = $result3['comments'];
```

The attributes are then arranged in a table and echoed out within the while loop.

Comment: Bothering to use capital letters and punctuation may inspire others to help you more.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable input...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a job for the DISTINCT keyword (info [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html)). You weren't super clear on what your schema looks like, but working from what you provided:

```
$test = @mysql_query("select distinct instance_id from comments where user_id = '$idd'");
```

This will perform the selection, then ignore any redundant rows in the result, so you'll get each thread/instance that the user commented in, but each thread will only appear once.